# Python : Scraping Instagram IGTV data, but it only shows information about first 24 records

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape instagram IGTV data (e.g., video title, views, likes, comments etc.) First I was using only **BeautifulSoup** but I was only able to take first 12 video details. Then I started using **Selenium**, now I'm able to get first 24 video details. But I've to scrape all the videos.

Below code gives me hyperlinks for the first 24 videos, then I'm **scraping** video details from each of the hyperlink:

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
#import json

url = 'https://www.instagram.com/agt/channel/?hl=en'
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
page = driver.page_source
driver.quit()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

#print(soup)
video_links=[]
for a in soup.find_all('a', class_='_bz0w', href=True):
    video_links.append('https://www.instagram.com' + a['href'])
print(video_links)
```

Please suggest me on how to get all the video details.

Answer (score 1):

you probably need to scroll down to load more results. 
You can do something like

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

to do so

Combining this with answer found [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986631/how-can-i-scroll-a-web-page-using-selenium-webdriver-in-python) so we can scroll down until end of page is reached:

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
#import json

url = 'https://www.instagram.com/agt/channel/?hl=en'
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get(url)
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 1

# Get scroll height
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height


page = driver.page_source
driver.quit()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

#print(soup)
video_links=[]

for a in soup.find_all('a', class_='_bz0w', href=True):
    video_links.append('https://www.instagram.com' + a['href'])
print(len(video_links))
```

Comment: Even after using this I'm getting max of 24 hyperlink. The channel link has more than 100 videos

Comment: please see my edit. this gives me 41 links. might need to play around with the scroll_pause_time value

Comment: This code returns around 37 results but it doesn't have any order. I was hoping to get the first 37 hrefs

Comment: you could adapt code to grab the results in between scrolls