# Scrape dynamic Website where content is loaded as you scroll

Tags: python, web-scraping

I dont know the right term but I think "dynamic website" might do the trick.
By that I mean that as I scroll, resources are being loaded.
I searched for solutions and I came across webdrivers, personally I dont like a whole browser being loaded, just for the purpose of scrolling down.
A different approach would be looking at the network tab and scraping the url, that I find there.

https://www.immowelt.de/liste/hamburg/wohnungen/mieten?prima=700&sort=relevanz&cp=1

However the content really gets loaded as I scroll.

the link that gets shown when I open the network tab and scroll down: https://www.immowelt.de/liste/getlistitems

Im new to web development so I dont get how these links that I see in the network tab can be named exactly identical but hold different values.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the network packet more closely. You will see that it is a `POST` request and sends `form data` to that link. Looking at the form data more closely:

```
query: geoid=108020&etype=1&esr=2&prima=700&sort=relevanz&cp=1
offset: 12
pageSize: 4
```

You see that it sends an `offset`. That is what paging the next results.

Answer (score 0):

Just looked-up an interesting question (with answers) for a similar problem:

[How can I scroll a web page using selenium webdriver in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986631/how-can-i-scroll-a-web-page-using-selenium-webdriver-in-python)

> The answers point to the code:
>
> ```
> driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, Y)")
> ```
>
> *There are also infinite scrolling options in the linked Q&A*

You might want to establish a parameter of how many entries you want to scrape by setting-up the "scroll" script and printing the output once the scrolling is done.

Hope this helps, cheers!

Comment: thank you for your contribution, however i'll avoid using a driver since it would take too long