# cant scroll down list of likers on an instagram post using python and selenium

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

im trynig to get a list of likers from the firt instagram post of any user.when you run the code you get the error 'index out of range' because its not scrolling down.how can i scroll down??whats wrong??

```
def get_user_post_likers(self, user, limit=10):
    self.nav_user(user)
    sleep(self.random_number_gen())
    first_photo = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("eLAPa")
    first_photo.click()
    sleep(self.random_number_gen())
    likers_list_btn = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/article/div[3]/section[2]/div/div[2]/button/span")
    likers_list_btn.click() 
    sleep(self.random_number_gen())
    fbody = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/div/div")
    scroll = 0
    while scroll <5:
        self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollTop + arguments[0].offsetHeight;', fbody)
        scroll += 1
        sleep(2)
    likers_list = []
    for i in range(limit):
        likers = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name('FPmhX')[i]
        likers_list.append(likers.text)  
        print(len(likers_list)) 
    print(likers_list)
```

1. List item

   ```
   return likers_list
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27760083/12094377), you can use the following code:
`driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, Y)")`
where Y is the height (on a FullHD monitor it's 1080 (as per 1920x**1080**p).
You can then create a loop and always be changing your Y value to a different number (to make it scroll down continuously).