# use selenium to infinite scroll down don't work

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to use selenium to scroll down **infinitely** this webpage https://gfycat.com/discover/trending-gifs

I try this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r"C:\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get(url)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")    

driver.quit()
```

But no scroll down happened.

I also tried:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

for i in range(10):
     driver.find_element_by_css_selector('html').send_keys(Keys.END)
```

But no scroll down happened too.

Comment: Since the page doesn't have a fixed scroll height, I would suggest to try something like - 

`for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  driver.executeScript('window.scrollBy(0,350)', ''); 
}`

This shall at least scroll down 5 times, you can change the value in for loop and keep scrolling down.

Comment: Try this it should work `for i in range(10):
   driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.END)
   time.sleep(1)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986631/how-can-i-scroll-a-web-page-using-selenium-webdriver-in-python for infinite scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

For infinite of Scrolling website you can using this methods of coding in Selenium as you can see I am using `while` for making infinite in addition you should be import `time` module for time out of loading website

```
def scroll(driver):
    timeout = 5

    # Get scroll height
    last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

    while True:
        # Scroll down to bottom
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

        # load the website
        time.sleep(5)

        # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
        new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
```