# How to scroll to the bottom of page using selenium python?(using find_element_by_xpath())

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath-2.0, js-scrollby

I am trying to scroll the page using scrollBy function but it is not applicable as I am using XPath to find the element(find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='sc-bGbZqa carTxV']")[Inspect in chrome with out adding Id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6Lgj.jpg). But while inspecting in chrome when I give id(TEST) [Inspect in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQ5lp.png) and try scrollBy function using id it is working fine. I am using selenium python. Your help on this is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I scroll a web page using selenium webdriver in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986631/how-can-i-scroll-a-web-page-using-selenium-webdriver-in-python)

Answer (score -1):

[Link for java](https://www.guru99.com/scroll-up-down-selenium-webdriver.html)  here i have attached page scroll to you in java pls go through and use this as python (Logic is same)