# How can I scrape from websites that have infinite scrolling?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, bots

I have managed to create a web scraper that can collect the item descriptions however the page loads more items as it scrolls.

```
from selenium import webdriver 
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from numpy import mean

namelist=[]
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://waxpeer.com/")
time.sleep(15)



links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='lpd_div']/a")
```

I also need the item description to format as:

```
★ Karambit| Gamma Doppler (Factory new)
```

rather than:

```
★ Karambit

Gamma Doppler

Factory new
```

```
desc = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='lpd_div']/div[2]/p")
for item in desc:
    print(item.text)
```

Comment: You will have to scroll and load everything before you can do what you need to do.

Comment: But how do I do that through selenium or other means?

Comment: [Duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986631/how-can-i-scroll-a-web-page-using-selenium-webdriver-in-python)

Comment: duplicate the whole code?

Comment: What? By duplicate I meant that the question has been asked before and you can just use that question to solve yours.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43299513/11177720) on the question does answer your question.

Comment: I also looked at the API. I noticed that there are near duplicate entries if using a loop to make requests to this. The difference only being in price. What did you want to do about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to use `Selenium`. The data is available via sending a `GET` request to the websites API in the following format:

```
https://waxpeer.com/api/data/index/?skip={offset}&sort=best_deals&game=csgo&all=0
```

with the `offset` of + 50 for every page.

---

For example, to print the names:

```
import requests

URL = (
    "https://waxpeer.com/api/data/index/?skip={offset}&sort=best_deals&game=csgo&all=0"
)

offset = 0

while True:
    try:
        response = requests.get(URL.format(offset=offset)).json()
        for data in response["items"]:
            print(data["name"])
        print("-" * 80)
        offset += 50
    except KeyError:
        break
```

Output:

```
★ Karambit | Gamma Doppler (Factory New)
★ Karambit | Gamma Doppler (Factory New)
★ Karambit | Gamma Doppler (Factory New)
★ Butterfly Knife | Doppler (Factory New)
★ Butterfly Knife | Doppler (Factory New)
★ Karambit | Gamma Doppler (Factory New)
★ Karambit | Gamma Doppler (Factory New)
...
...
```

Comment: Thanks that helps a ton, I don't know what i was thinking

Answer (score 1):

This is what I currently have to scrape an infinite scroll page.

```
def scroll():
  items = self.w.until(ec.presence_of_all_elements_located(self.item_locator))
  ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(items[-1]).perform()
  loader = self.driver.find_elements(*self.loader_locator)
  if loader:
    return True
  return False
```

The ActionChains part will find the last item and scroll to it causing the page to send a request for more stuff. This subsection of a test I have just verifies the infinite scrolling works, but if you want to do anything with the elements found you could append the items to a master list.

self.w is WebDriverWait by the way.

Comment: This is helpful for other projects however the previous answer is just easier in this example but thanks.