# Scroll a web page using selenium webdriver in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am currently using selenium webdriver to parse through this webpage (https://startup-map.berlin/companies.startups/f/all_locations/allof_Berlin/data_type/allof_Verified) to extract all startup urls using Python. I tried all relevant methods mentioned in this post: [How can I scroll a web page using selenium webdriver in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986631/how-can-i-scroll-a-web-page-using-selenium-webdriver-in-python) and also other suggestions online.

However, it did not work out for this website. It only loaded the first 25 startups. Some code examples:

```
from time import sleep
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

webdriver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver')

# Write into csv file
filename = "startups_urls.csv"
f = open(BLD / "processed/startups_urls.csv", "w")
headers = "startups_urls\n"
f.write(headers)

url = "https://startup-map.berlin/companies.startups/f/all_locations/allof_Berlin/data_type/allof_Verified"

webdriver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)

# Get scroll height
last_height = webdriver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    webdriver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(3)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = webdriver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height

htmlSource = webdriver.page_source
page_soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlSource, "html.parser")
startups = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "type-element type-element--h3 hbox entity-name__name entity-name__name--black"})
if startups != []:
    for startup in startups:
        startups_href = startup.a["href"]
        startups_url = "https://startup-map.berlin" + startups_href
        open_file.write(startups_url + "\n")
else:
    print("NaN.") 
              
f.close()
driver.close()
```

Any suggestions? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the indication of the scrolling process according to the position of the `vertical-thumb` element.
So what you can do is to get the `translateY` value of it's style and compare it with it's previous value similarly to how you currently trying to compare the `new_height` with `last_height`.
That element can be located by this `cssSelector`: `#window-scrollbar .vertical-thumb`
So you can do the following:

```
element = webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector("#window-scrollbar .vertical-thumb")
attributeValue = element.get_attribute("style")
```

Now the `attributeValue` string contains something like this

```
position: relative; display: block; width: 100%; background-color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.6); border-radius: 4px; z-index: 1500; height: 30px; transform: translateY(847px);
```

Now you can find the substring containing the `translateY` and extract the number from it as following:

```
index = attributeValue.find('translateY(')
sub_string = attributeValue[index:]
new_y_value = int(filter(str.isdigit, sub_string))
```

In case `int(filter(str.isdigit, sub_string))` doesn't work properly (while it should) try using instead it

```
new_y_value = re.findall('\d+', sub_string)
```

To use `re` you have to import it first by

```
import re
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I got this error message: "int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'filter'" Could you please clarify a bit more?

Comment: OK, we need to debug this. Unfortunately I have no Python installed on my machine at all, so I will ask you several questions. So, when debugging does `attributeValue` contains string with values like in the answer? Then does index presents int number? What contains the `sub_string`?

Comment: yes,  ```attributeValue``` shows ```'position: relative; display: block; width: 100%; background-color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.6); border-radius: 4px; z-index: 1500; height: 499px; transform: translateY(0px);' ``` I used ```index = attributeValue.find('translateY(0px);')```, which returns 151. I did not use ```index = attributeValue.find('translateY(')```, which returns -1. ```sub_string``` contains ```'translateY(0px);'```

Comment: Good, so the problem is really with the last code line. If so please "import re" and try "new_y_value = re.findall('\d+', sub_string )". I will update the answer as well to be clear

Comment: Thanks. ```new_y_value``` returns ```['0']``` but it does not help me to web scrape. Could you please let me know where I should place the code for my code in the question?

Comment: Sure, you already know how to scroll page down. F.e. with `webdriver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")` 
So just scroll page down and get the new `new_y_value` and compare it with the previous value of if exactly like you compared it to last_height

Comment: sorry, it still scraped only the first 25 items.

Comment: Wait! As I see from your code you first scrolling until the scrolling is stopped and only after that, not inside the `While True:` block, you are dealing with the `href` links. So, in this manner you will anyway get the amount of links presented on a single screen, no more

Comment: thanks. so there is nothing I can do about it?

Comment: First please let me know: when you run the current code, the page is scrolled. Yes?

Comment: nope, it is not. But anyway, thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://startup-map.berlin/companies.startups/f/all_locations/allof_Berlin/data_type/allof_Verified")
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#window-scrollbar .vertical-track")


a = driver.switch_to.active_element
a.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
```

just use Keys.PAGE-DOWN

Comment: Thanks. I just tried, but it did not work out either. It shows the error message "WebElement' object has no attribute 'page_source". I just updated the code in the question. Could you please let me know what it is wrong? Thanks a lot.