# Unable to retrieve links using beautiful soup and python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract all the url under the url :
https://www.scotts.com/en-us/library/lawn-food

I have realized is that it does not returns few urls such as
https://www.scotts.com/en-us/library/lawn-food/when-feed-greener-lawn
and few more

I have mentioned below my code snippet:

```
import time
from random import randint
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import re
```

```
def scrape_google_summaries(url):
    time.sleep(randint(0, 2))  # relax and don't let google be angry
    r = requests.get(url)
    content = r.text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser",parse_only=SoupStrainer('a', href=True))
    summary=[]
    for link in soup:#.find_all('a'):
        summary.append(link.get('href'))
        
    return summary
```

```
output = scrape_google_summaries("https://www.scotts.com/en-us/library/lawn-food")
```

Comment: Website loads data using javascript. I believe that's the reason why aren't getting the expected result.

Comment: That site is being loaded by JavaScript. Use ```Selenium```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked by saving the `r.text` that is `content` to a local file and then i opened that in my browser and as expected all those article links that you are trying to scrape were not there..! Which means all those links are being dynamically generated.And beautifulSoup isn't considered for **scraping** dynamically generated website content.You will have to use some other tool like `selenium` or `requests_html`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using selenium and it's scroll down functionality.

More information here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27760083/8623540