# scroll to bottom of page before scraping with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

There is a web page that I want to run my **scraping** script on. However, because the page refreshes with additional content when you scroll down, I need to be able to add a function to my script that scrolls the web page all the way to the bottom before my **scraping** script is run.

In attempt to achieve this, please find my entire script which seems to stop at row height 5287.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import csv
import pandas as pd  
   
#Initialize a Chrome browser
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:.............chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")

#Go to the page we want to scrape
driver.get('https://icodrops.com/category/ended-ico/')

#Open csv file to write in 
csv_file = open('icodrops_ended_icos.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
writer.writerow(['Project_Name', 'Interest', 'Category', 'Received', 'Goal', 'End_Date', 'Ticker'])

page_url = 'https://icodrops.com/category/ended-ico/'
# Although only one page to scrape - need to scroll to the bottom to pull all data
lastHeight = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
print('lastHeight', lastHeight)
while True: 

    driver.execute_script(f"window.scrollTo(0, {lastHeight});")
    time.sleep(15)
    #height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
    newHeight = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
    print('newHeight', newHeight)
    
    if newHeight == lastHeight:
        break
    lastHeight = newHeight


    try:

        #print the url that we are scraping
        print('Scraping this url:' + page_url)

        #Exract a list object where each element of the list is a row in the table
        rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="col-md-12 col-12 a_ico"]') 
        
        # Extract detail in columns from each row
        for row in rows:
            #Initialize a dictionary for each row
            row_dict = {}

            #Use relative xpaths to locate desired data
            project_name = row.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="ico-row"]/div[2]/h3/a').text
            interest = row.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="interest"]').text
            category = row.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="categ_type"]').text
            received = row.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@id="new_column_categ_invisted"]/span').text
            goal = row.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@id="categ_desctop"]').text
            end_date = row.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="date"]').text
            ticker = row.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@id="t_tikcer"]').text


            # Add extracted data to the dictionary
            row_dict['project_name'] = project_name
            row_dict['interest'] = interest
            row_dict['category'] = category
            row_dict['received'] = received
            row_dict['goal'] = goal
            row_dict['end_date'] = end_date
            row_dict['ticker'] = ticker


            writer.writerow(row_dict.values())


    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        csv_file.close()
        driver.close()
        break
```

Without being able to scroll to the bottom of the page my script will only **scrape** data form the initial page which only constitutes about 10% of all that is available

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Cheers note taken - I have update

Comment: without URL for this page we can't see what is wrong.

Comment: if you use ``print()`  to see what you have in variables then you see that `scrollTo` doesn't give value but `None` - and finally you get `newHeight = None` and `lastHeight = None` so `if newHeight == lastHeight` gives `if None == None`

Comment: I tested code with your URL and problem can be that server detects Selenium and it doesn't send new content - JavaScript gets HTML with message `"This website is using a security service to protect itself from online attacks."` with status `403` - so browser can't add new data and scroll it. So real problem is different then you expect.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `print()` to see values in variables then you see that `scrollTo` gives `None` and you can't use it to get `newHeight`.

---

Minimal working code.

I tested on page http://quotes.toscrape.com/scroll created for learning scraping.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/scroll'

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

lastHeight = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
print('lastHeight', lastHeight)

while True:

    driver.execute_script(f"window.scrollTo(0, {lastHeight});")
    time.sleep(1)    
    newHeight = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
    print('newHeight', newHeight)
    
    if newHeight == lastHeight:
        break
    
    lastHeight = newHeight
```

---

**BTW:**

I found on Stackoverflow answer from 2015 which use the same method but with `document.body` instead of `document.documentElement`

[How can I scroll a web page using selenium webdriver in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27760083/1832058)

So if this code works for you then this question could be closed as `duplicate`

Comment: Thanks but didn't seem to work. I have updated to include my entire code which might make it easier for you to assist

Answer (score 0):

I always use the below piece of code to scroll till bottom, and I have never seen that it fail.

```
driver.execute_script("var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;")
```

So, your effective code will be

```
while True:

    driver.execute_script("var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;")
    height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
    newHeight = driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, " + str(height) + ");")
    time.sleep(15)
    if newHeight == lastHeight:
        break
    lastHeight = newHeight
```

Comment: Thanks but didn't seem to work. I have updated to include my entire code which might make it easier for you to assist