# How to load all elements of a page using selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I know this has been answered before, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986631/how-can-i-scroll-a-web-page-using-selenium-webdriver-in-python). But none of this seems to work in my case. I am trying to load all the elements of a particular class using chromedriver in selenium. The driver only gets 60 for each page and moves on to the next one in the loop I have added to the script. The url bellow doesn't send to an infinite loading page (like social networks) but I think it dynamically loads more elements as I scroll down. If I open developer tools and look for the targeted XPATH, all the elements get found. Is there a way to replicate that?

[Targeted url](https://browzine.com/libraries/1374/subjects/57?sort=title)

Answer (score 0):

For your case, you should scroll not window, but the scrollable element.

```
driver.execute_script("var el = document.getElementsByClassName('infinite-scroller')[0]; el.scroll(0, el.scrollHeight)")
```

And you should put this in a loop and wait for more elements loaded, e. g. until total target elements count will stop increasing.