# How to scroll element Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

How to scroll through an element using Selenium?[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986631/how-can-i-scroll-a-web-page-using-selenium-webdriver-in-python Be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've used selenium, but doing something like this should scroll until the desired element is in view using JavaScript.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("your-site.com")

# Find element by ID or some other method
element = driver.find_element_by_id("id_of_element")
# Run JavaScript to scroll until the element is in view
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```