# Webscraping with Selenium unable to fully scrape data

Tags: python, html, pandas, selenium

Trying to scrape a webpage for bond information. While using Selenium allows me to get data for the first few rows of the table containing the wanted data, some rows and columns of data are not being scraped. I do not know why.

The webpage is [webpage containing bond information](https://www.sgx.com/fixed-income/retail-fixed-income-securities?code=sgsbonds)

The input code:

```
a = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'sgx-table-row')

combined=[]

for num in range(len(a)):
    combined.append([])
counter=0
for item in a:

    ticker = item.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'a')
    name = item.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'sgx-table-cell-text')
    price1 = item.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'sgx-table-cell-number')
    
    for item in ticker:
        if len(item.text) != 0:
            combined[counter].append(item.text)
        else:
            pass
    for item in name:
        if len(item.text) !=0:
           
            combined[counter].append(item.text)
        else:
            pass
    for item in price1:
        if len(item.text) != 0:
            
            combined[counter].append(item.text)
        else:
            pass
    counter+=1
    


df = pd.DataFrame(combined)
print(df)
```

The output code:

```
 N518100E 230201  CMHS   99.000      99  0.827   98.173     ﹣     ﹣     0   
1   N519100A 240201  LSHS   97.000      97  0.945   96.055     ﹣     ﹣     0   
2   N520100A 251101  QGES        ﹣       ﹣  0.111        ﹣     ﹣     ﹣     0   
3   N521100V 261101  IRRS        ﹣       ﹣      0        ﹣     ﹣     ﹣     0   
4   NA12100N 420401  PH1S  110.000     110  0.842  109.158     ﹣     ﹣     0   
5   NA16100H 460301  BJGS  108.000     108  1.069  106.931     ﹣     ﹣     0   
6   NA20100F 500301  ZL8S  108.000     108  0.729  107.271     ﹣     ﹣     0   
7   NA21200W 511001  ZFGS   87.000      87      0       87     ﹣     ﹣     0   
8   NX13100H 230701  R1MS  101.500   101.5  0.157  101.343     ﹣     ﹣     0   
9   NX15100Z 250601  AFUS   99.701  99.701  0.331    99.37     ﹣     ﹣     0   
10  NX16100F 260601  BJHS  102.000     102  0.296  101.704     ﹣     ﹣     0   
11  NX18100A 280501  CMGS   90.000      90  0.585   89.415     ﹣     ﹣     0   
12  NX21100N 310701  RXYS        ﹣       ﹣  0.093        ﹣     ﹣     ﹣     0   
13  NY07100X 220901  7PMS  101.380  101.38  1.214  100.166     ﹣     ﹣     0   
14             None  None     None    None   None     None  None  None  None   
15             None  None     None    None   None     None  None  None  None   
16             None  None     None    None   None     None  None  None  None   
17             None  None     None    None   None     None  None  None  None   
18             None  None     None    None   None     None  None  None  None   
19             None  None     None    None   None     None  None  None  None   
20             None  None     None    None   None     None  None  None  None   
21             None  None     None    None   None     None  None  None  None   
22             None  None
```

As seen, past a certain point, the find_all method returns None even though the html code in the webpage is in the same format (same class names and tags).

Comment: Have you tried scrolling down the element? [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986631/how-can-i-scroll-a-web-page-using-selenium-webdriver-in-python) (probably need to pass a little different script to scroll down the specific element, but you get the idea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page is loading dynamically, and it calls a couple of APIs, receiving some json data from them.
Would the following result help you?

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('https://api.sgx.com/securities/v1.1/bonds?params=nc%2Cadjusted-vwap%2Cbond_accrued_interest%2Cbond_clean_price%2Cbond_dirty_price%2Cbond_date%2Cb%2Cbv%2Cp%2Cc%2Cchange_vs_pc%2Cchange_vs_pc_percentage%2Ccx%2Ccn%2Cdp%2Cdpc%2Cdu%2Ced%2Cfn%2Ch%2Ciiv%2Ciopv%2Clt%2Cl%2Co%2Cp_%2Cpv%2Cptd%2Cs%2Csv%2Ctrading_time%2Cv_%2Cv%2Cvl%2Cvwap%2Cvwap-currency')
df = pd.DataFrame(r.json()['data']['prices'])
df
```

This returns a dataframe with 38 rows × 34 columns:

```
    pv  bond_dirty_price    lt  fn  trading_time    dp  type    du  bv  dpc ... p_  p   bond_accrued_interest   change_vs_pc    s   nc  cx  vl  v   bond_date
0   1.014   101.4   1.014   None    20220722_090753 None    retailbonds None    45.0    None    ... X   0.000   0.501   None    1.019   RMRB    0.0 45.0    45630.0 1658419200000
1   0.998   99.7    0.997   None    20220722_090824 None    retailbonds None    22.0    None    ... X   -0.100  0.380   None    1.000   5A1B    0.0 41.0    40874.0 1658419200000
2   0.964   96.3    0.963   None    20220722_090824 None    retailbonds None    7.0 None    ... X   -0.104  1.068   None    0.966   6AZB    0.0 82.0    79028.0 1658419200000
3   1.013   101.3   1.013   None    20220722_090824 None    retailbonds None    20.0    None    ... X   0.000   0.678   None    1.015   V7AB    0.0 80.0    81040.0 1658419200000
4   1.011   101.3   1.013   None    20220722_090825 None    retailbonds None    22.0    None    ... X   0.198   0.983   None    1.013   V7BB    0.0 9.0 9117.0  1658419200000
```

Comment: You are a genius. To be honest, i dont know how it works but it contains most of the information I want. Will you be able to explain a little, I was always under the impression that web scraping required either bs4 or selenium or some other scraping library, thanks !

Comment: Hi , I was wondering how you managed to "generate" an api. Is it possible using the requests library, or did you get it from the sgx website itself.

Comment: I did *not* generate an API. I opened Dev Tools - Network tab in Chrome, and reloaded the page. And I inspected the network calls made by the scripts in that page. One of the urls accessed was the one above: I looked at the answer (in json format) and it appeared to show some meaningful data.