# How to scrape links and images by using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, coding-style

**I want get the links and images of these character**

[image: Charecter]

**Website Link**

[https://opensea.io/collection/meebits?search[sortAscending]=false&search[sortBy]=FAVORITE_COUNT](https://opensea.io/collection/meebits?search%5BsortAscending%5D=false&search%5BsortBy%5D=FAVORITE_COUNT)

**XPATH SELECTION CODE**

```
coll_name = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//h1')
coll_desc = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="sc-1xf18x6-0 sc-1aqfqq9-0 sc-1y1ib3i-7 haVRLx dfsEJr eGsklH"]')
profiles = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@role="grid"]/div')
for profile in profiles:
    art_name = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '/div[@class="sc-7qr9y8-0 sc-dw611d-1 iUvoJs fcpvjL"]')
    art_price = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="sc-7qr9y8-0 iUvoJs Price--amount"]')
    art_link = driver.find_elements(By.LINK_TEXT, '(//link/@href)[16]')
```

**FOR LOOP CODE**

```
for c in coll_name:
    collection_name.append(c.text)
    time.sleep(1)


for d in coll_desc:
    collection_desc.append(d.text)
    time.sleep(1)

for n in art_name:
    artname.append(n.text)
    time.sleep(1)

for p in art_price:
    price.append(p.text)
    time.sleep(1)
    
for l in art_link:
    link.append(n.text)
    time.sleep(1)
```

**PLEASE HELP ME IN SOLVING THIS ISSUE**

Comment: it is simpler if you create minimal working code (with all needed imports) - so we could simply copy and run it. It can use it to make modifications. It also shows if you use your parst of code correctly - you have to use nested loops. And describe what is the problem - if you get wrong result then show it. We can't run code and we can't read in your mind - you have to describe all destails in question (not in comments)

Comment: if you want to search inside `profile` then you should use loop(s) `for n in art_name:` inside loop `for profile in profiles:` and you should use `profile.find_elements(...)` with path starting with `.`  - `//.//div...` (instead of `drive.find_elements(...)`) to use `relative xpath` instead of `absolute path`

Comment: don't you get error? In `for profile in ...` you use `find_element` without (`s`) - so it gets only one element, not list of elements, and you can't use it with `for`-loop because it will raise error. If you get error then you should show it in question.

Comment: this page uses `lazy-loading` - it adds images and names when user scrolls down page - and in code you have to also scroll down page to load elements. It may need to use javascript in `driver.execute_script()`. You can find it in some other questions on Stackoverflow

Comment: [How can I scroll a web page using selenium webdriver in python? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986631/how-can-i-scroll-a-web-page-using-selenium-webdriver-in-python)

Comment: ok, I got it and  i want to get inner details of items. for that i have to go item than back to items then get 2nd item detail.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will scroll the page, get the items on it, scroll again, and so on. Selenium setup is for linux, you just need to pay attention to imports, and to the code after defining the driver/browser:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time as t
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")


webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)

df_list = []
url = 'https://opensea.io/collection/meebits?search%5BsortAscending%5D=false&search%5BsortBy%5D=FAVORITE_COUNT'
browser.get(url)
while True:
    try:
        items = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@role='grid']/div[@role='gridcell']")))
        for item in items:
            print(item.text)
            print('______________')
    except Exception as e:
        continue
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")
    t.sleep(5)
```

A couple of notes:

- pay attention to imports, and how elements are waited to load in the pagee, before trying to locate them
- look up the specific details you need for each item (careful: some items have incomplete details, so use try/except for each of item's details), create a tuple with all item's elements, and append it to the df_list initialized at the beginning of the code. You will be able to transform that list of tuples in a dataframe, once you got all elements
- the code as it is now is an infinite loop; you need to write a condition to break the loop once there are no more elements to be loaded
- if you have issues understanding anything I wrote above, please revisit the basics of Python and Selenium 4.

Comment: I want to get the link of items. for that, what's the scenario?

Comment: above code is not giving links of items

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service: you need to hire someone for that. My response above gave you a **way** of achieving what you want. You need to do the legwork: for example, instead of printing out `item.text`, you can print out `item.get_attribute('outerHTML')`, inspect the idividual elements, and extract them. Good luck.