# how to scrape website with infinite scroll?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I want to scrape website in which, when we scroll down scrollbar the new data starts loading. how to scrape this website?

```
hospitals2 = []

for i in range(1,10):
    try:     
        element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, paths[i]) 
        hospital_name=element.text
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",element)
        hospitals2.append(hospital_name)
    except AttributeError:
        hospitals2.append("hospital name not found")
```

I tried above code but new data is not loading.

Comment: What's the url?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I scroll a web page using selenium webdriver in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986631/how-can-i-scroll-a-web-page-using-selenium-webdriver-in-python)