# Selenium Webdriver - click on hidden elements

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, hidden-field

I am trying to automate upload file functionality in Google Drive.

The element used to pass parameters is hidden with height - 0px.

None of the user actions would make this element visible. So I need a work around to click on the element while it is not visible.

```html
<input type="file" style="height: 0px; visibility: hidden; position: absolute; width: 340px; font-size: inherit;" multiple=""/>
```

The xpath for the above element is -

```
//*[@class='goog-menu goog-menu-vertical uploadmenu density-tiny']/input
```

I am using

```
WebDriver.findElement(By.xpath(<xpath>).sendKeys(<uploadFile>)
```

Exception -

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException
```

- Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with.

I have tried using JavascriptExecutor. But unable to find the exact syntax.

Comment: Take a look at the HTML, is Google Drive just a form? If so, don't use Selenium, just write a script to post a form with data you specify.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this:

```java
WebElement elem = yourWebDriverInstance.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='goog-menu goog-menu-vertical uploadmenu density-tiny']/input"));
String js = "arguments[0].style.height='auto'; arguments[0].style.visibility='visible';";

((JavascriptExecutor) yourWebDriverInstance).executeScript(js, elem);
```

The above bunch would change the visibility of your file input control. You can then proceed with the usual steps for file upload like:

```java
elem.sendKeys("<LOCAL FILE PATH>");
```

Be aware, by changing the visibility of an input field you are meddling with the application under test. Injecting scripts to alter behavior is intrusive and not recommended in tests.

Comment: Does this work for the hidden element available in Appium Android platform too?

Answer (score 14):

Simple solution:

```
WebElement tmpElement = driver.finElement(ElementLocator);
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", tmpElement);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this sample code:

```
JavascriptExecutor executor= (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("document.getElementById('ID').style.display='block';");
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ID")));
select.selectByVisibleText("value");
Thread.sleep(6000);
```

By using java script executor and make the element visible then click on the element through ID. Hope it hepls..

Comment: Why do you need thread sleep? executeScript should be synchronous

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
WebElement elem = yourWebDriverInstance.findElement(
   By.cssSelector(".uploadmenu > input"));
String js = 
  "arguments[0].style.height='auto'; arguments[0].style.visibility='visible';";
((JavascriptExecutor) yourWebDriverInstance).executeScript(js, elem);
```

Here I have replaced XPath by CSS Selector. Let me know Is the above scripting is working or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can give the following a try:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("$('.goog-menu.uploadmenu > input').click();");
```