# How to upload a file in Selenium WebDriver with no 'input' element

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have a HTML page with button named "Upload" and id: `btn-import-questions`. The element:

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm col-lg-11" id="btn-import-questions" data-ts-file-selector="questions-import-init">  Upload&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-upload"></i></button>
```

I tried a Selenium Java code like this:

`driver.findElement(By.id("btn-import-questions")).sendkeys("C:/path/to/file.xlsx");`

But since this is an upload button and not an input-type element, the above code is not working.

Comment: What happens when you click this button manually?

Comment: Window popup will appear immediately and asking for the file path with open and cancel button

Comment: And when you choose a file using this pop up window, will the name of this file appear somewhere on the page after the pop up disappears?

Comment: After providing the file path and click on open, suddenly the popup window disappears and the data in the file are imported to my application.

Comment: Is your window showing uploaded file path..?? Once check it directly on website.

Comment: No file upload is an java-script code , In popup window i have given the file path and click on open,the data is directly imported to my application

Comment: you can use auto it script and call the exe file from selenium

Comment: You can try to trigger this javascript using Selenium

Answer (score 7):

Check the DOM because somewhere there must be an `<input type="file">`. The website's javascript will call the .click() of this element to pop up the file selector dialog and closing the dialog with a selection will provide the path. With Selenium the same can be achieved with the .sendkeys():

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type=\"file\"]")).sendkeys(localFilePath);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are doing it almost correctly, except that **`sendKeys()` should be called on the input with `type="file"`** that is, most likely invisible in your case. If this is the case, make the element visible first:

- [Selenium Webdriver - click on hidden elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12363038/selenium-webdriver-click-on-hidden-elements)

Answer (score 2):

This one works for me:

```
    String CSVFile = "C:\\D\\Projects\\file.csv";
WebElement fileElement=this.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[text()='fileElement']"));
            this.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(fileElement ));
            fileElement .click();

            StringSelection ss = new StringSelection(CSVFile);
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss, null);

            //native key strokes for CTRL, V and ENTER keys
            Robot robot = new Robot();

            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use AutoIT tool to do this.
Use below code in AutoIT .Au3 file to upload.

```
sleep(1000)
If WinExists("[TITLE:Open]") Then

 Local $hWnd = WinWaitActive ("[TITLE:Open]", "",15)
 WinActivate($hWnd)
 ;WinWaitActive("Open", "", 10)
 ControlFocus("Open","","Edit1")
 ControlsetText("Open","","Edit1",$CmdLine[1])
 ControlClick("Open","","Button1")

ElseIf WinExists("[TITLE:File Upload]") Then

 Local $hWnd = WinWaitActive ("[TITLE:File Upload]", "",15)
 WinActivate($hWnd)
 ;WinWaitActive("Open", "", 10)
 ControlFocus("File Upload","","Edit1")
 ControlsetText("File Upload","","Edit1",$CmdLine[1])
 ControlClick("File Upload","","Button1")

Else

 Local $hWnd = WinWaitActive ("[TITLE:Choose File to Upload]", "",15)
 WinActivate($hWnd)
 ;WinWaitActive("Open", "", 10)
 ControlFocus("Choose File to Upload","","Edit1")
 ControlsetText("Choose File to Upload","","Edit1",$CmdLine[1])
 ControlClick("Choose File to Upload","","Button1")

EndIf
```

And then use below code in you C# code to invoke it.

```
String sExe=(<EXE file path>+" "+<Upload file path>);

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(sExe);
Thread.sleep(5000);
```