# java - org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am trying to select a group from the search bar. Any tips on how to make element visible?

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='global-search-box-item-0']")).click();
```

Below is the HTML structure.

```
<div role="option" id="global-search-box-item-0"><i aria-hidden="true" 
class="comments outline circular icon _2BaEJYulOrH2_i6ZYf-DdV" xpath="1" 
style=""></i><div class="_58oiWFV24V4GmIFrAnwPx"><div class="title">**Test 
Automation** HE Community PRIVATE Group</div><div class="description">**Test 
Automation** HE Community PRIVATE Group </div></div></div>>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium Webdriver - click on hidden elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12363038/selenium-webdriver-click-on-hidden-elements)

Comment: Please show HTML and a screenshot to illustrate which element you want to select.  If your app has public access URL, please give it too.

Comment: Please show some piece of code.

Comment: May be you have a duplicate xpath, please do double check.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not visible, then the page logic should be changed to make it visible, if that's what you want?

You could hack your way around it with a javascript executor.

```
WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='global-search-box-item-0']"));

((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeAsyncScript("args[0].style.display='block';",webElement);
```

Or else if it exists on the page and is visible, then this xpath would only return you the visible version of the element.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='global-search-box-item-0' and not(ancestor::*[contains(@style, 'display: none')])]")).click();
```