# How to upload file with selenium on Linux machine without using sendKeys method?

Tags: java, selenium, file-upload

How to upload files with selenium on a Linux machine without using the sendKeys method?

Note: There is no input field for using the sendKeys method. 
Below is the locator of the input field to upload a file.

[image]

Comment: Depends on how the site is doing file uploads.

Comment: Via API if it's available. You won't need Selenium for it.

Comment: I want to automate the file upload section of the site using selenium for testing purpose

Comment: May be it is best you can add more details about the Website like page source etc. Sometimes the input field to upload a file is hidden. If so, you can enable it using JS.

Comment: What's about Robot? Have you tried?

Comment: @Prophet: Yes tried from local. My question is if I want to run it from Jenkins have to give the relative path of the file like - System.getProperty("user.dir"). Is it possible?

Comment: @Ayaz: I have added the required image of the locator of the input field to upload the file.

Comment: Your local machine is Windows, right? I am not sure Robot will run on Linux that's why I asked. And I also know that Robot doesn't work on Windows in headless mode. So it's a problem...

Comment: WAIT! You have and input element there! Send the file path to it!

Comment: Actually, there is no input field to send the file path using the sendKeys method. Only a button is available to select the file from a window.

Comment: No local machine is also Linux (ubuntu). OK in headless mode it will not work. Thanks for this info. Then I think it will not work on the Jenkin server with a Linux machine right when run on headless mode?

Comment: I can see the input with type="file" and id as `search-by-img-face_image` ... Is it not the same input field you want to send the keys to?

Comment: @DesertPride: Yes it is the same input. I cannot use the sendKeys method as there is no text field in the frontend to send the file path.

Comment: It is possible to make the invisible input field visible through javascript executor just before sending the keys. Then again make it to "display : none;" as it was before ... here are the steps : 1. change the visibility of input field to visible 2. send keys 3. change the visibility back to false. try the solution given here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12363038/selenium-webdriver-click-on-hidden-elements/12364198#:~:text=arguments%5B0%5D.-,style.,of%20your%20file%20input%20control.

Comment: @DesertPride: Thanks a lot for your help!! It is working now :) . As per your comment I enabled the hidden text field with javascript executor and able to send the file path with sendKeys method.