# Scroll element to the middle of the screen with selenium

Tags: java, selenium

Is there any way to scroll an element to the middle of the screen?
I tried:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element);
```

But it always scrolls on the top.

Comment: solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20167544/selenium-scroll-element-into-center-of-view

Comment: js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getScreenSize()/2)");

Answer (score 2):

### scrollIntoView()

The [**`scrollIntoView()`**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_scrollintoview.asp) method scrolls the specified element into the visible area of the browser window.

Syntax :

```
element.scrollIntoView(alignTo)
```

Parameters :

- alignTo(Boolean) : An optional parameter where :

  - `true` : the top of the element will be aligned to the top of the visible area of the scrollable ancestor
  - `false` : the bottom of the element will be aligned to the bottom of the visible area of the scrollable ancestor.
  - `skipped` : it will scroll to the top of the element.

**Note** : Depending on the layout of other elements, some elements may not be scrolled completely to the top or to the bottom.

---

As per your *usecase* as you want to scroll element to the middle of the screen instead of using **`scrollIntoView()`** as an alternative you can *scroll the window* using either of the following options :

- *Scrolling Down* :

  - **`scroll()`**

    ```
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("scroll(0, 250);");
    ```
  - **`window.scrollBy()`**

    ```
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", "");
    ```

Comment: I tried everything ...When I scroll element my element is on the top and is covered by a headband. The headband always covers the first element.

Comment: found solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20167544/selenium-scroll-element-into-center-of-view

Answer (score 2):

As I can see this question already have some good answers, But there are many ways you can do **scroll Down/scroll up** in **selenium**. out of all those ways I would like to add one more to this question.

You can use Action class for this purpose :

**Code**

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN).build().perform();
```

you can call `sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)` multiple times as per your requirement. Like this :

```
action.sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN).build().perform();
```

and so on !

One of the other way is go with JavaScript. @Ishita Shah have already provided that solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().text(\"Text of element upto which you want to scroll down\"));");
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll according to Web Page sections,

If you wants to scroll web page, by middle. It means go for bottom position up to required:

Syntax:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,200)");
```

It will scroll vertically down.

Answer (score -2):

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: 'center', inline: 'nearest'});");
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.