# How to scroll to an element in Ruby and Selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium

I am trying to scroll to an element using javascript executor on my Ruby script using selenium. However, the script scrolls all the way down of the page and skips the element. Thus not interacting with the element.

Scroll method:

```
def scroll_into_view(element, locator=nil)
    element = element.nil? ? find(locator) : element
    @wd.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);', element)
  end
```

Reference:

```
scroll_into_view(nil, gear_icon_span_locator)
```

Do you know of any other ways to scroll to an element in ruby?

I've tried action builders and actually moving to an element, that didn't seem to work.

Comment: I use 'arguments[0].scrollIntoView();' without passing the true parameter and it scrolls right to the element.  Have you tried that?

Comment: Tried it, it is scrolling all the way to the bottom of the page and the element is skipped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script that worked is this, I found the answer from here: [Scroll that works for ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20167544/selenium-scroll-element-into-center-of-view)

```
  def scroll_to_element(element, locator=nil)
    script_string = "var viewPortHeight = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);" +
        "var elementTop = arguments[0].getBoundingClientRect().top;" +
        "window.scrollBy(0, elementTop-(viewPortHeight/2));"
    element = element.nil? ? find(locator) : element
    execute_script(script_string, element)
  end
```

Comment: Use WATIR which is a wrapper around Ruby Selenium Binding where you can find watir-scroll gem which will help you.

Comment: We're not using watir for this project, for different purposes

Comment: Okay no problem.

Answer (score 0):

In watir you can scroll to element using the below.

```
element.scroll.to :bottom
```

Comment: It's suppose to scroll to the element bottom.

Comment: Not sure why, but it didn't do anything.

Comment: Using selenium webdriver 3.13.0 and ruby 2.5.3

Comment: Do you have `gem 'watir-scroll'` in your gemfile? Or did you installed `'watir-scroll'` gem?

Comment: We're not using watir for this project, for different purposes