# scroll down with selenium

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i'm using python selenium package and i'm trying to scroll a page to the bottom.. although, the site which i apply the selenium is dynamic (dynamic loading) which means it doesn't really scrolled to the bottom of the page.

after i read, and i find in the selenium documentation i was able to get that solution:

```
for i in range(25):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

this is not good enough for me, because sometimes the page needs much more iterations, and sometimes much less for getting to the bottom of a page.

is there a get function so i can use if statement, something like:

```
for i in range(25):
    if driver.current_position == driver.document_height:
        break
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

so, when i get to the end of the document i won't wait for nothing and break the loop.

or maybe if i can check how many pixels i jumped and if it's zero i will break the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to use a `while` loop, and break out of the loop once you hit the bottom of the page, rather than have a set number of iterations in a `for` There's a good discussion on one way to do this, here: [Scrolling down a page with Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21753130/scrolling-down-a-page-with-selenium-webdriver)