# Selenium - Scroll to Element

Tags: java, selenium

Is there any way to scroll page to current webElement using selenium for Java?

I would like to click on element but when the element is down or up it clicks on another place - so I want to scroll page to current element.

I searched but havent found any solution.

Any help - Advance Thanks !

Comment: This answer is the one, that has been working for me all the time.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/20487332/4193730

Answer (score 0):

You need look up the id and fire click event on that id.
I want to click on next button on my page whose id="nextButton"
In the page object here is how i declared. That way you dont need  worry about where the position is
Eg:

```
@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "nextButton")
private WebElement next;
```

More info at 
http://reddymails.blogspot.com/2011/09/selenium-2-or-webdriver-for-automation.html