# How to search for element in dynamic loading grid on scroll using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, ajax, selenium, selenium-webdriver

There is Grid which has say 1000 rows with a column named Username(with distinct values).

And the grid will display only 20 rows per view, and the other rows will be **loaded**(ajax) only on scrolling.

So, how to search for a particular username in the grid, since we have only elements getting loaded on scroll.

Does `Scrollintoview` method help? Or do i need to use `window.scrollby()` until i find the searched item?

Comment: Check this : http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-finding-webelements-using-map/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, I apologise because I had never worked on a grid before. I thought it will be a frame and will be easier to switch and then scroll to the element using **JavascriptExecutor**. But, alas! That's not the case for a grid. 
**And, there must be a table when a grid is involved.**

Now, this is what has worked for me. 


First click on any visible element on grid to get it into focus.

Then scroll the grid using grid's locator(xpath,id,etc.) using 'Keys.PAGE_DOWN' till you find the element you are looking for.

In case the element is not found on each scrolls, than handle the exception it raises and scroll again.

**Note: Do not forget to give some sleep time after each scroll.**

I have automated one sample grid, and have attached the sample working code below. Hope this helps in figuring out problem:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class ScrollGrid{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException{


        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/PagingAndScrolling/VirtualPaging.aspx");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        //Clicking on an element inside grid to get it into focus
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ContentHolder_ASPxGridView1_DXMainTable']//td[.='9/30/1994']")).click();

        WebElement ele=null;
        int flag=0;
        int count=0;

        do{
            try{
                //element to search for while scrolling in grid
                ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ContentHolder_ASPxGridView1_DXMainTable']//td[.='3/28/1996']"));
                flag=1;
            } catch(Throwable e){
                //scrolling the grid using the grid's xpath
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ContentHolder_ASPxGridView1']//div[2]")).sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN);
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            }
        }while((flag==0) || ((++count)==250));

        if(flag==1){
            System.out.println("Element has been found.!!");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Element has not been found.!!");
        }

        highlightElement(driver, ele); //For highlighting the element
        Thread.sleep(5000L); //to check if the element scrolled to is highlighted.
        driver.close();
    }

    //For highlighting the element to be located after scroll
    public static void highlightElement(WebDriver driver, WebElement ele) {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
            {
                JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
                js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', arguments[1]);",ele, "color: red; border: 2px solid red;");
            }
        }
        catch(Throwable t)
        {
            System.err.println("Error came : " +t.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

**Note:** This works correctly now. It will come out of the loop in case the element is found, or if not found after 250 scrolls. '250' is a relative number. You can change it to the number of scrolls you want to perform on the grid.

Comment: @Vignesh, I have fixed the above code for the count of scrolls. Hope this helps you out better.

Comment: This answer provides some insight on how to handle these kind of scenarios. !!

Answer (score 1):

I would take "ScrollintoView" any day.
It will scroll and check for the element simultaneously and halt when it has the element on view 
For help with the code, please follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20487332/4193730)

Comment: How does it work with the scroll bar inside the grid?

Comment: The grid must be inside a frame. So, first you need to switch to the frame using `driver.switchTo().frame(//index or "//name or id of frame" or "Webelement inside frame")`
Then, you can use the scrollIntoView method to scroll to the element.

Comment: what if it is not inside iframe or inside a table?

Comment: Please share the HTML code snippet of the grid or at least the link of the webpage in which you are trying to automate the grid. It will be easy to deduce the issue then. :)

Comment: i have edited my question, i'm looking for some poc/ method to know which one works best for that kind of scenario

Comment: Can you provide any solid example for this scenario if possible?

Comment: I have provided one example below. Please review it and let me know if it helps.