# Selenium webdriver ‘jqwidgets – jqxgrid ‘ data grid with java: How to scroll and get the rows visible?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jqxgrid

Selenium webdriver ‘jqwidgets – jqxgrid ‘ data grid with java: How to scroll and get the rows visible?

I want to get all the cell value's from a 7 columns JQXgrid table. This is a dynamic loaded data grid with row count will be updated when page gets refreshed. But more than 6 row's will not be visible at a time. User needs to scroll down to get the next 6 rows. Problem is: Selenium cannot read the data which is not visible. We can find the xpath of the vertical scroller to go down to get the next 6 rows to make it visible.

How can i solve it dynamically loaded JQXgrid to get all the values from the table?

---

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If it is similar to an ajax grid , this link might solve your problem. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/26797156/4193730

Here, a working example of scrolling and finding an element inside a grid is given.