# Selenium not working with JQWidgets listbox or Datagrid

Tags: selenium, datagrid, listbox

I am testing my web site using Selenium IDE 2.9.0 for Firefox.
My web site uses JQWidgets.

Selenium seems to work fine until you need to simulate clicking on a list item or selecting a row from a data grid.

I have seen other posts similar to this problem like this one

[Selenium webdriver ‘jqwidgets – jqxgrid ‘ data grid with java: How to scroll and get the rows visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26823644/selenium-webdriver-jqwidgets-jqxgrid-data-grid-with-java-how-to-scroll-and)

but I can't work out the problem.

When I use the record button to record my interaction with the website it shows the following :-

command=click
target=//div[@id='listitem1site_list']/span

When I double click on this to execute the command it does not select the line in my list.

I have tried mouseDown and clicking on the outer div first and every combination.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?  I'm facing the same issue.