# Selenium Python not finding the element

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriver, element

I'm trying to click on some element but it's not working:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='ENG']")
```

When I add:

```
driver.maximize_window()
```

before click action, it works, other codes are not working again.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem
When I was looking for an element, it was not yet available in the code.

Fixed by adding

```
driver.implicitly_wait(30) ## 30 is the time he will wait
```

before searching for the element.

This line makes the code wait until the entire page is loaded before looking for an element.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to click on some element via driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='ENG']"), but it's not working,

You need to post logs or be more specific. Are you getting an error on the call to find_element_by_xpath(), or when you call click as you mention below?

> when I add driver.maximize_window() before click action, it works,
> other codes are not working again, please advise which can be the
> reason

The relevant code needs to be provided.  I believe you're saying that when you call maximize_window() before you locate the element, it works, but if you don't call maximize window, it fails. This could be for a variety of reasons, but it sounds Javascript related. A similar question like this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26729532/how-to-search-for-element-in-dynamic-loading-grid-on-scroll-using-selenium-webdr) could help. If maximize window doesn't actually help the issue, I would look into [implicit waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#implicit-waits) or [WebDriverWaits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait).