# Selenium. How to get a list of items when the list is scrolled?

Tags: php, powershell, selenium

Good afternoon.
I want to get a list of artists on Deezer.com
But only I get the first results. But the artists more if the page to scroll down - they appear.
How, then, to get the whole list? thanks in advance

Comment: Those are most likely added dynamically via AJAX. Simply recheck the page periodically using a timer/sleep. There might/should be an existing answer.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium IWebElement.Text will be empty for not visible elements, this is how it works.

You have two options with Selenium -

- Scroll the page down via [Actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28473710/how-to-scroll-to-element-with-selenium-webdriver-using-c-sharp) or JavaScript
- Get inner text or html of an element via [JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047056/how-to-read-text-from-hidden-element-with-selenium-webdriver)