# How to scroll to an element in java

Tags: java, selenium

I have a question about scrolling to an element. I have this code below where I can filter out how to click an element based on its name:

```
public class LandingPage extends BasePage {

  public LandingPage(WebDriver webDriver) {
    super(webDriver);
  }

  By cardBody = By.className("card-body");

  public void clickCard(String cardName) {
    List<WebElement> elements = webDriver.findElements(cardBody);
    click(
        elements.stream()
            .filter(element -> element.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(cardName))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            .get(0));
  }
}
```

I want to do a similar thing but instead of clicking on an element, I want to scroll to the element. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to scroll to element with Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28473710/how-to-scroll-to-element-with-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 0):

to scroll to a specific element in Java-Selenium bindings, we use `JavascriptExecutor` like below.

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", ele)
```

here `ele` is a `WebElement` where you want to `scrollIntoview`

Since you have a list of web elements, `elements` in your case, you could probably use `elements.get(0)` or `elements.get(1)`.

or best way would be to iterate through the list and have `JavascriptExecutor` in your loop.

Something like :

```
for(WebElement ele : elements){
  ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", ele)
  // do some stuff with ele. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For `true` it scrolls element to the top and for `false` it scrolls element to the bottom. In below code I am scrolling till last element of the list.

**Code**:

```
  JavascriptExecutor javascriptExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
  List<WebElement> optionList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("xPath to list of elements"));
  int lastElement = (optionList.size() - 1);
  javascriptExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(false);",optionList.get(lastElement));
```

If you want to scroll till specific element then you can pass the element id.

```
javascriptExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(false);",optionList.get(3));
```