# Unable to get elements from scroll window

Tags: c#, selenium, testing, xpath, nunit

I encountered difficulties testing my GUI. I have a window with elements which I get with code using selenium xpaths or ids. There are a lot of them so the window is scrollable. The problem occurs when I try to get elements that are not visible in the window (the ones that we can only see when we scroll).
All of these "under the scroll" elements are unable to be fetched.

Does anyone know how to get the hidden elements? I would be grateful for any help :)

Comment: [Solution in java to scroll element into view](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20487332/4193730) and perform any action on it . Hope you will be able to imitate the same in C#

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scroll Element into View with Selenium](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401343/scroll-element-into-view-with-selenium)

Comment: I do this all the time and it just scrolls the window automatically... no special code. If you really need to do this for some reason, this is a duplicate of other SO questions.

Comment: I am also agree with jeffC because there is no need of special code. It is automatically done. if your element is not still appear on page then try to wait to get load page once.