# Scroll down in a browser using VBA

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, browser, web-scraping, scroll

I was trying to find a way to scroll (down, up) a webpage with vba.

I have a page where I need to fill in some information. This part is working. The only thing, it happens somewhere down there and I would like to see it happening so I need to scroll the window down in a way... is there a trick?

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: What packages (references) are you using? Ex, if you're using selenium, this might help :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401343/scroll-element-into-view-with-selenium

Answer (score 1):

You can execute javascript to scroll on the page e.g.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub ScrollWindow()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollBy"
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        .document.parentWindow.execScript "window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight);", "javascript"
        Stop '<== Delete me
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello and thanks for your reply. I'm not using selenium.. But I did find a way to get around it:
1. Simply by using:

`SendKeys "{Down}"`

2. But this wasn't accurate enough so I did this:

`.Navigate "web-address" & "#location-name"`

As stated when inspecting the element.

I hope my findings can be helpful for someone out there ;)

Thanks again for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

This is the code to scroll to the bottom of the page

```
Sub ScrollToDown()
    Url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        .navigate Url
        .Visible = True
        While ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
        .document.parentWindow.execScript "window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight||document.documentElement.scrollHeight);", "javascript"
    End With
End Sub
```