# Scroll up and down to get Element into View with Selenium Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I need to be able to scroll up and after that down to find some element with Selenium.
I already saw many questions and answers, the main idea I found is `self.web_driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)` and this is what I currently have in my code. But this is not good enough since this code is scrolling down only so this fails to find the element in case it is located in the upper part of the rollable view.
So I need a script that first scrolls up (page Up?) and after that begins scrolling down.
I tried something like this

```
self.web_driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element) 
self.web_driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, -document.body.scrollHeight);")
self.web_driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
```

but this doesn't scroll up :(

Comment: An element is (just only one) element, why are you scrolling up and down again and again to get the element into view? The position of any element must be a fixed unless DOM changes.

Comment: Because this function (find_the_element) should be universal, sometimes the element is in the upper side and some times in the down side of the view and i can't know where it is. I need to pass the XPATH to the function and it will find (click on) the element

Comment: Exactly, irrespective of the element being located up or down, will be brought into view. You simply have to pass the xpath. No need of scrolling up or down in particular.

Comment: But it doesn't work!
self.web_driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element) 
scrolls down only!
No matter if is it true or false inside the script

Comment: `scrollIntoView` should scroll in any direction. Can you share the URL to a page where that's not the case?

Comment: Also, why does the function need to be "universal"? Are you trying to write a helper function to use everywhere in your test suite?

Comment: I can't share the page, but yes, this is a helper function. The automation here is based not on selenium directly but on selenium_helper

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try below code to scroll page up:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

self.web_driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.HOME)
```

Another way (preferred) you can scroll up to required element:

```
element = self.web_driver.find_element_by_xpath('SOME_XPATH') # you can use ANY way to locate element
coordinates = element.location_once_scrolled_into_view # returns dict of X, Y coordinates
self.web_driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo({}, {});'.format(coordinates['x'], coordinates['y']))
```

Comment: Doesn't `location_once_scrolled_into_view` scrolls the element into the view by default and then return the co-ordinates? Why to invoke `execute_script('window.scrollTo())` again?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seem that this property was changed, so in last versions it just returns the X, Y coordinates without scrolling to element

Comment: If the definition is considered it says `Use this to discover where on the screen an element is so that we can click it. This method should cause the element to be scrolled into view.`  and as the call to `click()` is involved without the _scrolling_ the method is not making any sense to me either.

Comment: @DebanjanB, this is initial description and scroll can be executed only in case `if self._w3c` returns `True`, but default value for WebElement object is `self._w3c = False`, so `else` block is executed by default - no scroll

Comment: @Andersson after the first euphoria I see that your solution is not really works good. It since works better than the previous code but not really scrolls up... I need to debug to see what and why doesn't work good in my code.  The problem is that this is not my code but a code of a person worked here before me and leaved me that strange code...

Answer (score 3):

I have discovered a `handy tricky hacky stuff` over the years (I've been using Selenium for 150 years).

Whenever you're unable to scroll up a form, just ***send keys into an input*** on the top of the page. The driver will find it and will automagically scroll up the page to perform the action.

Whenever I think about this trick, I realize being an old man isn't that bad.

Good luck you fresh sailor, see you on the shores of Selenia.

Answer (score 3):

Try this, it works good:

```py
view_port_height = "var viewPortHeight = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);"
element_top = "var elementTop = arguments[0].getBoundingClientRect().top;"
js_function = "window.scrollBy(0, elementTop-(viewPortHeight/2));"

scroll_into_middle = view_port_height + element_top + js_function

driver.execute_script(scroll_into_middle, element)
```

Comment: I no more working there so I even can't try this solution :) but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3):

This was very useful for me:

```
WebElement scrolling = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
            .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("classSomething")));

//SCroll Down
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollTo(0, arguments[0].scrollHeight)", scrolling);

//Scroll Up
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollTo(0, arguments[0].scrollUp)", scrolling);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with also `getBoundingClientRect()` and `scrollTo()`

```
self.web_driver.execute_script("coordinates = arguments[0].getBoundingClientRect();scrollTo(coordinates.x,coordinates.y);", element)
```

I tested and it goes up and down.

Comment: FYI Python property `location_once_scrolled_into_view` do exactly the same as what JavaScript `getBoundingClientRect()` method do

Answer (score 2):

If you defined driver as `webdriver.Chrome()` or `webdriver.Firefox()`,you can use this code for scrolling up:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.HOME)
```

Also, for scrolling down, you can try this code:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", scr1)
```

`scr1` is your box xpath which you want to scroll it.
You can scroll to middle of the page by this code, too:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollWidth", scr1)
```

Answer (score 0):

For java I use next expression:

```
  WebElement element = drv.findElement(By.xpath("//div"));
  (drv as JavascriptExecutor).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element);
```

The snippet scroll down to an element in Selenium until it is visible