# Increase size of non interactive desktop

Tags: selenium, windows-10

I am running selenium tests through a service (CruiseControl.NET) using the Administrator account (it seems to fail if I run it as the system user).

In the tests, I am running an instance of chrome via chromedriver.exe so there is a browser window which size I ultimately want to control.

If I run it as Administrator, it seems that I cannot have the service interacting with the desktop so it will use the non interactive window station.

The name of  window station is `Service-0x0-3e7$` and the name of the desktop will be `Service-0x0-3e7$\default`.

The resolution in that desktop seems to be 1024x768 and my work computer has a resolution of 2560x1440 so the tests will be running under different conditions compared to when I run them locally, which is undesirable.

Why is the the desktop `Service-0x0-3e7$\default` of this size? Can I change it?

Comment: Did you use in Selenium tests the screen resolution?

Comment: @RatmirAsanov In the tests, I am running an instance of chrome via chromedriver.exe so there is a browser window which size I ultimately want to control.

Comment: I mean are you using something like that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49424277/selenium-and-dimension-of-device/49424556#49424556?

Comment: @RatmirAsanov My question is about the size of the non interactive desktop.