# How to scroll vertically down till my desired text is displayed

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scroll

I tried

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("windows.scrollBy(0,500)");
```

And

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element);
```

And

```
WebElement lastElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("value of locator"));
int y = lastElement.getLocation().getY();
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,"+y+")");
Thread.sleep(3000);
```

My window's scroll bar is moving down but I want to scroll my application's scroll bar. [image]

As in the attached image after clicking o settings it is opening further options & I have to scroll to see below options

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scroll Element into View with Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401343/scroll-element-into-view-with-selenium)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your code trials I think you were pretty close. You need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be visible* first and then use `executeScript()` method to `scrollIntoView` as follows:

```
WebElement lastElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("xpath_of_the_desired_element"))).click();
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",element);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's how i scroll to an element of my DOM ( with jquery, tell me if you need vanilla ) :

```
$('#elementToScroll').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#scrollToThisElement").offset().top - $(window).height() / 2
 }, 0);
```

This code will center verticaly the .scrollToThisElement