# How to scroll up and down HTML DOM without window.scrollBy(x, y) (I need to scroll down in an element)

Tags: javascript, html, css, selenium, dom

I want to scroll down with my selected document. 
Tried the below code.

```js
window.scrollTo(x, y);
const body = document.getElementsByClassName("body")[0];
body.scrollTo(x, y);
```

But, sometimes returns "undefined".

**Edit 1:**
I got the solution. Provided the snippet below that helped me.

1. To scroll hole page:

> window.scrollTo(x, y)

2. To scroll selected div (it should have a long area in order to be able to scrolled down):

> document.getElementsByClassName("body")[0].scrollTo(x, y)

Comment: Thank you. Also, you should use the `querySelector` document method instead of `getElementsByClassName`. It is more versatile. Check it out here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: pls separate your question and your answer and post a real answer

Comment: Read this: [scroll element into view with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401343/scroll-element-into-view-with-selenium)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is code to scroll till particular element in DOM.

C#

```
var element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(xpath));
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```

Java

```
var element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(xpath));
JavaScriptExecutor js = (JavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```

let me know if this doesn't resolve your issue. am happy to help further