# Scrolling down with Python Selenium on part of the web page

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So I have a web page where a part of the page is a user list. A user can scroll down this list, but scrolling only works if the mouse pointer is located above this list. Keys like page down or end do not work.

I can locate the element using Selenium and Xpath without any issue, but I don't know how to perform the scrolling in selenium as it only works when the focus is on that specific web element.

I've tried sending keys like page down and end or code like

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

Anybody got any ideas?

Comment: Can you share url?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scroll Element into View with Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401343/scroll-element-into-view-with-selenium)

Comment: Solved it through a workaround by selecting a visible element and then sending an end key through actionchains.

Answer (score 0):

Because you mentioned you can locate the element, you could try scrolling to the specific element, instead of using `document.body.scrollHeight` as your scroll target.

```
element = driver.find_element(someLocatorHere)

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
```

Hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Scrolling can be achieved in two different ways.

**Javascript**

```
 elementId = driver.find_element_by_id("elementId")
 driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", elementId)
```

**Action class**

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(elementId).perform()
```