# How can I scroll down with selenium until the bottom of the screen is the very top? (py)

Tags: python, html, selenium

With selenium (or any module I guess) I need to scroll down until the bottom of a page I am on is the top of the page. I have not really tried anything because I could not find any info that would help me online; I couldn't even hope to figure it out.

Example:
[image: the arrow you see at the bottom of page would barley not be visible, it would be if you scrolled at all though]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I scroll a web page using selenium webdriver in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986631/how-can-i-scroll-a-web-page-using-selenium-webdriver-in-python)

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi Not really, I need to scroll until the content of the page is just barley not visable. That shows how to scroll X distance or to the bottom. I don't know how to go until the content is gone.

Comment: post some url example

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi Not the page I am trying to do but lets go with the twitter homepage.
you go from here:
https://imgur.com/a/VjlJZUw
to where the bottom of the browser is:
https://imgur.com/a/0Wx7eGV

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401343/scroll-element-into-view-with-selenium

Comment: Do you need to go specifically to the bottom of the viewport or to a specific element? Also, do you need to execute the scroll on the click of a button or something else?

Comment: @Shiverz I just need to scroll down the height oh my browser (excluding the tab and extension thing) nothing else.