# How to scroll elements like x-table-container (selenium c#)

Tags: c#, selenium

When I inspected for a scroll bar it pointed the element .x-table-container, tried to scroll with the following code, but it's not working, is there any other solution for this?

```
    protected void DragAndDropToVertical(IWebElement webElement, int dragValue)
    {
        new Actions(Driver).DragAndDropToOffset(webElement, 0, dragValue).Build().Perform();
        PauseExecution(200);
    }
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "it's not working."

Comment: @Connell.O'Donnell the element is not scrolling down.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with Action chain it is usually not working when there is an iframe html in main body or element is not in view. So i think you should use Javascript Execute instead, this usually work best for me. Try it your self:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("find element with id or using what ever you want"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
Thread.sleep(500);
```

This code will scroll until it find your element.

### Reference

[Scroll Element into View with Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401343/scroll-element-into-view-with-selenium)