# use chrome search(Ctrl+F) in selenium with java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have one project and use selenium and chrome driver; I want use Ctrl + F in page and when open find bar type word in text box find bar and click in next or previous button in find bar;
For open find bar i do this:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F);

            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

please help to continue

Comment: Why would anyone want to do that ?

Comment: Because i want to show word in page and next capture screenshot with java

Comment: Is it something like you want to write in excel file or PDF file ?

Comment: Yes. when take screen shot i want to use in pdf file but i think is diffrent with write to pdf

Comment: You just want to highlight the word so it shows up in your screen shot? Should be fairly straight forward to do...

Comment: Are you able to get the web element ?

Comment: Much better approach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401343/scroll-element-into-view-with-selenium. Just collect elements by text than scroll view and collect screenshots in a loop.

Comment: Yes  DMart.how can to do this?

Comment: i cant use element. Because site use this code:

Comment: embed id="plugin" type="application/x-google-chrome-pdf" src="https://www.pishkhan.com/Archive/1400/03/14000303/ArmanMeli651141109710948515150151.pdf" stream-url="chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/fb9307e6-3c6b-4e1b-8b15-4a0ac3053271" headers="accept-ranges: bytes
cache-control: public, max-age=600,public
content-length: 14264883
content-type: application/pdf
date: Mon, 24 May 2021 15:30:26 GMT
expires: Mon, 24 May 2021 15:40:26 GMT
last-modified: Sun, 23 May 2021 19:46:48 GMT
" background-color="4283586137" javascript="allow" full-frame="" pdf-viewer-update-enabled=""

Comment: looks like you've got it working... sending keys and hitting enter, and then enter again for next should do it...  another alternative may be to just execute a javascript function... create one for HighLightText which takes the text as an argument.

Comment: Yes  pcalkins.I can do it if i know the word,but when i got word from user, how can do this?

Comment: Please add more details to the question. Right now the question is very vague and doesn't explain what is the issue and what issue are you facing? This question is bound to be closed.