# Scroll in a specific div Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium

I want to scroll a specific division in selenium java
[image]

As you can see in the picture there are two divs, by default the left one has the scroll thing so if u scroll it scrolls in that

I want to scroll in the division on the left but I cant set focus to it by clicking something in it cause that makes it go to another page.

Thanks

Comment: Please don't post images of HTML. Please share it along with question.

Comment: Please update your question with your code and its failure including stacktrace if getting any exception.

Comment: @pburgr it doesnt have an error I am just asking how can i scroll in a specific division

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401343/scroll-element-into-view-with-selenium

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code,

```
/*
 * By
 * scroll to the element and wait
 */
public void scroll(By element) {
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", driver.findElement(element));
    log.info("Scrolling down");
    wait_for_("scroll");
}
```